# Install Powershell script with WiX

Tags: command-line, powershell, wix, windows-installer

I have a signed PowerShell script which I want to deploy to a target machine via a WiX installer. Is it possible to give the script the execution rights?

Regards,
  forki

- EDIT -
  It seems I have to call Powershell with --Command Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned, but I can't get it working. I see the Powershell command window opening but it doesn't change the policy.

> ```
> <Property Id="POWERSHELLEXE"><![CDATA[C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe]]></Property>
>
> <CustomAction Id="AllowPS"
>   Property="POWERSHELLEXE"
>   ExeCommand="-NoLogo -NoProfile -Command Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned"
>   Execute="deferred"
>   Return="check"/>
>
> <InstallExecuteSequence>
>    ..
>   <Custom Action="AllowPS" Before="InstallFinalize"/>
>    ...
> </InstallExecuteSequence>
> ```

Comment: It seems I have to call Powershell with --Command Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned, but I can't get it working.

Comment: Are you using PowerShell 1.0 or 2.0 on the target machine?

Comment: We have Win 7 - so I think it's 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group Policy is the better way to go about it,

I think the reason that your call to PowerShell.exe is not changing the execution policy is because the cmdlet is set to prompt the user before changing the execution policy.  The  -Force parameter will force the change without an additional prompt.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PowerShell 2.0, there is a -ExecutionPolicy parameter on PowerShell.exe.  Try something like this in one single custom action to run the script.

```
ExeCommand="-NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File <scrptpath>"
```

Comment: You've got a typo - should be 'RemoteSigned'

Answer (score 1):

I will set the ExecutionPolicy via group policies.